# Ubuntu Graphical Error

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

When I start an app I get graphical errors:

[image]

I've tried swapping RAMs and rebooting system and it's still the same. So what should I do now please?

**Specs:**

```
AMD Athlon X2 5000+ 
2GB DDR2 RAM
320GB DW HDD
Gigabyte motherboard
Integrated Graphics
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 AMD64

Comment: It is a very bad idea to install 16.04 64-bit with 2GB of RAM. It won't work well either way. I am using it on 4 GB of RAM with only Chrome with 5 tab  opened. 2.6GB is used.

Comment: So what version do you recomend for this?